# Scrapy xpath returning result for every row in table not just selected ones

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following Scrapy code which is supposed to return the word "GOAL" for every time an instance of the Span element 'title="Goal"' is found:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "goal"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.selector.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]'):
            list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"]')

            if list_of_goals:
                print "GOAL"

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal'])
```

However, it is instead returning a string of "GOAL" for all 47 rows in the table entitled 'Wayne Rooney's Match History'.

Can anyone see why it is not only returning instances where a goal was scored in that match?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression `'//span[@title="Goal"]'` with double-slash on the beginning iterates over all nodes of the current document. Is this what you intended?

If you want to iterate only the current row's descendants, try `'.//span[@title="Goal"]'`, where dot explicitly sets the starting point of `//` iteration to the current context node, or simply `'descendant::span[@title="Goal"]'` from the current node.